# Unit Testing Atomic Kotlin, how can I activate it?

Tags: kotlin

I want to use something called [AtomicTest](https://www.angus-liu.cn/Atomic-Kotlin-zh/se06-ch06.html). I put at the top:

```
import atomictest.eq
```

But it is not working. I got an error saying: **Kotlin: Unresolved reference: eq**

Is there anything that I have to do in order for this test to work?

Comment: Is AtomicTest a library? Does your project have a dependency on it?

Comment: Here is a link about it: https://www.angus-liu.cn/Atomic-Kotlin-zh/se06-ch06.html. I'm following a book and it uses it but it didn't tell me how can I use it!

Comment: Looks like the library is just one file: https://www.angus-liu.cn/Atomic-Kotlin-zh/appendix-a.html

Comment: Maybe but how can I use it?

Comment: I'd just create a file under my project and paste it there.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy [AtomicTest.kt](https://github.com/BruceEckel/AtomicKotlinExamples/blob/5bcf85b6024095a8237bb1f43448bdaf640f3c94/Examples/AtomicTest/AtomicTest.kt) from [AtomicKotlinExamples](https://github.com/BruceEckel/AtomicKotlinExamples) to your project.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32208692)